# Using MIT Kerberos as account domain for Windows AD Domain

Tags: linux, authentication, active-directory, interop, kerberos

We have mostly Linux users who login via Kerberos. But we also have a few (<50) users who use both Linux and Windows. This is supposed to grow in the future. 
We would like to keep our User database on the Unix/Kerberos side.

But for some reason that eludes me I can not get it to work yet.

I did the following after reading some guides (domains anonymized):

1) Add the ADDC to /etc/krb5.conf on the linux KDC and Linux hosts

```
AD.DOMAIN = {
            kdc             = PDC.AD.DOMAIN
            admin_server    = PDC.AD.DOMAIN
            default_domain  = ad.domain
    }
```

2) Add cross realm principals on the Linux side

```
addprinc -pw <longPW> -requires_preauth krbtgt@AD.DOMAIN
addprinc -pw <longPW> -requires_preauth krbtgt/LINUX.REALM@AD.DOMAIN
addprinc -pw <longPW> -requires_preauth krbtgt/AD.DOMAIN@LINUX.REALM
```

3) Add realm info via ksetup to Windows ADDC and other Windows machines

```
ksetup
default realm = ad.domain (NT Domain)
LINUX.REALM:
    kdc = kdc.linux.realm
    kpasswd = kdc.linux.realm
    Realm Flags = 0x0No Realm Flags
Mapping all users (*) to a local account by the same name (*).
```

4) Add Two-Way trust on Windows side via

```
netdom trust /d:LINUX.REALM ad /add /PT:longPW /realm /twoway
```

Check returns

```
nltest /TRUSTED_DOMAINS
List of domain trusts:
0: LINUX.REALM (MIT) (Direct Outbound) (Direct Inbound) ( Attr: non-trans )
1: AD ad.domain (NT 5) (Forest Tree Root) (Primary Domain) (Native)
The command completed successfully
```

But also

```
netdom trust lst /d:LINUX.REALM /verify /KERBEROS /twoway
The command failed to complete successfully.
```

5) Add mapping to users

```
altSecurityIdentities for user ad\test shows kerberos: test@LINUX.REALM
```

I can login with ad\test (which is not what I want) but I **can not** log in as test@LINUX.REALM which is what I wanted

On the other hand:

```
kinit test@AD.DOMAIN
Password for test@AD.DOMAIN:
root@kdc:~# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: test@AD.DOMAIN

Valid starting    Expires           Service principal
21/07/2017 13:24  21/07/2017 23:24  krbtgt/AD.DOMAIN@AD.DOMAIN
    renew until 22/07/2017 13:24
```

**My problem**:
I cannot login on the windows side with principals test@LINUX.REALM. As written in the topic we want the Linux Realm to be the account domain, not the AD, which should be possible as well, shouldn't it? We only want to have to handle account creation, deletion etc. in the Linux Realm, having the Windows Users log in with their Linux Account/Password.

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of doing what appears to be cross-realm authentication (that's what it appears), why not just have *all* Linux clients point back to AD for Kerberos authentication?  Linux can join AD with the Centrify client.  Then you're only managing one directory service.

Comment: @JohnRSmith >> Linux can also join AD with raw SSSD configuration, if you don't want to invest in Centrify licenses (or in licenses of its competitors). But having witnessed how the "notPetya" malware could **destroy** the AD infrastructure of a multinational company (along with 50,000 desktops/laptops), I advise everyone to think twice before using a Windows-based technology for central authentication.

Comment: @JohnRSmith I do think migrating more than 400 User accounts and services to AD might be less trivial. Additionally the licensing cost for even more servers as well as the security concerns are also valid. As a last point, we do have more Linux than Windows knowledge here, so migrating to a Windows infrastructure might be detrimental.

Still thank you for your comment. I did indeed have a look at it before and we had discussed it.

Comment: @samsonscharfrichter That sounds indeed like a bad weekend experience. I do hope that you did not get too many grey hairs and that there were not too many casualties.

Comment: _"I can login with ad\test but will not get a TGT for the Linux realm"_ > is that really a problem? Your Linux users authenticate on Linux side, your Windows users authenticate on AD; so if your AD TGT allows you to create service tickets in the Linux realm _(disclaimer: I don't know how AD manages the equivalent of `[capaths]` configuration)_ and vice-versa, then it does not look too bad IMHO.

Comment: @samsonscharfrichter I guess my description was not clear enough, my mistake.
We want to handle accounts only on the Linux side, thus managing only one account database instead of two.
Sorry if that was not clear, I will edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing

```
ksetup /addhosttorealmmap .dns.domain LINUX.REALM
```

on each windows client mostly fixed this problem.

I can now login with user@LINUX.REALM to the windows client with correct mapping.